# Normalizing(Reshaping) data frame based on split and columns

Tags: r, dataframe, normalization

I have a data frame containing

```
df 
Date        name             score
12/09/2012  Mahesh\nRahul    120
13/09/2012  abc\nxyz\nrep         110
...........................
```

i have tried this in order to get atomic

```
name1=str_split(df[,2],"\n")
```

but dont know how to associate again ,what is the best way to make data frame normalize so that i can get

```
 df 
Date        name     score
12/09/2012  Mahesh   120
12/09/2012  Rahul    120
13/09/2012  abc      110
13/09/2012  xyz      110
13/09/2012  rep      110
...........................
```

any help to make normalized a long data frame in R.

**Edit**

please note that it is just a reproducible example ,i have multiple names in my **name** column and number of names varies from one row to other row .thanks.

```
dput(df) structure(list(Date = structure(1:2, .Label = c("12/09/2012", "13/09/2012 "), class = "factor"), name = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("abc\nxyz", "Mahesh\nRahul"), class = "factor"), score = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("110", "120"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Date", "name", "score"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). A good reproducible example will help others to tackle your question lot more easily.

Comment: Please give output of `dput(df)` so that we can reproduce `df` on our side

Comment: You are confusing the meaning of atomicity. To really get a `data.frame` to be an atomic vector just use `unlist( data.frame )`, but this will not get you the output you desire. This is a question about reshaping your data.

Comment: @geektrader dput(df) structure(list(Date = structure(1:2, .Label = c("12/09/2012", 
"13/09/2012 "), class = "factor"), name = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("abc\nxyz", 
"Mahesh\nRahul"), class = "factor"), score = structure(c(2L, 
1L), .Label = c("110", "120"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Date", 
"name", "score"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: next time i will definalty keep in mind how to properly write a reproducible exam,thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is relatively easy using `data.table` (and fast obviously).

```
require( data.table )
dt <- data.table( df )
dt[ , list( name = unlist( strsplit( name , "\n" ) ) ) , by = list( Date , score ) ]
#         Date score   name
#1: 12/09/2012   120 Mahesh
#2: 12/09/2012   120  Rahul
#3: 13/09/2012   110    abc
#4: 13/09/2012   110    xyz
```

As a note I took `df` to be the following data (note `character` classes over `factor` classes that appear in your actual data...

```
df <- read.delim( text = "Date    name    score
12/09/2012  'Mahesh\nRahul'   120
13/09/2012  'abc\nxyz'       110" ,
sep = "" , h = TRUE , quote = "\'" , stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
```

Comment: @Aashu did you read my note about how my data are different to yours? Specifically the fact you have `factor` in your data. Your comment is not very helpful without what you are getting. The code works on the input data as I show it.

Comment: df=read.csv("abc.csv", header = TRUE,quote = "\'" , check.names = TRUE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE ) ,hope it satisfy your condition.

Comment: @Aashu I don't think you need `quote` (I am not sure - I added it to make the data read correctly when I copy/pasted it in from your OP). I recommend you read your data in your normal way and *just add* the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an R base solution

### Update

```
> Names <- strsplit(df$name, "\n")
> n <- sapply(Names, length)
> data.frame(cbind(apply(df[,-2], 2, function(x) rep(x, n)), 
                   name=unlist(Names)), row.names = NULL)[,c(1,3,2)]
        Date   name score
1 12/09/2012 Mahesh   120
2 12/09/2012  Rahul   120
3 13/09/2012    abc   110
4 13/09/2012    xyz   110
5 13/09/2012    rep   110
```

where `df` is:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Date = c("12/09/2012", "13/09/2012"), name = c("Mahesh\nRahul", 
"abc\nxyz\nrep"), score = c(120, 110)), .Names = c("Date", "name", 
"score"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: +1 I agree with Matthew. Nothing ugly about this. Quite a practical solution. I think it does assume that the splits for all names are equal though right? Or am I misinterpreting?

Comment: thanks @MatthewPlourde and SimonO101, will delete the ugly adjective.

Comment: note, both of these ways assume there are only two names per row.

Comment: Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1302, 47 after R base sol dat1 <- cbind(dat1[,-6], To=c(do.call(rbind, strsplit(dat1$To, "\n"))))

Comment: @Jilber, you'll need to work some more on this to make it work with "unbalanced" data in the "name" column.

Comment: @Aashu, rather than just posting the error messages like you're doing, try to read them and understand what they are saying, then post a more meaningful comment.

Comment: @Aashu see my update, it works for any number of names now. I used your new data.frame ;). Ananda thanks for the comment

Answer (score 2):

To add to the alternatives, you can use `scan` to separate the string quite easily and `rep` and `cbind` to get the final `data.frame`

```
df
#         Date          name score
# 1 12/09/2012 Mahesh\nRahul   120
# 2 13/09/2012 abc\nxyz\nrep   110

scan(text=as.character(df$name), what = "")
# Read 5 items
# [1] "Mahesh" "Rahul"  "abc"    "xyz"    "rep"  

cbind(df[rep(rownames(df), 
             sapply(gregexpr("\n", df$name), length)+1), 
         c("Date", "score")], 
      name = scan(text=as.character(df$name), what = ""))
#           Date score   name
# 1   12/09/2012   120 Mahesh
# 1.1 12/09/2012   120  Rahul
# 2   13/09/2012   110    abc
# 2.1 13/09/2012   110    xyz
# 2.2 13/09/2012   110    rep
```

`read.table` also works to split the concatenated column:

```
read.table(text = as.character(df$name), sep = "\n", header = FALSE)
#       V1
# 1 Mahesh
# 2  Rahul
# 3    abc
# 4    xyz
# 5    rep
```

Answer (score 1):

There are already good answers here, but this is another way with base R using the `rle` and `inverse.rle` functions. @Jilber's base R solution is more elegant, but this way will work if your strings have more than two names.

```
df <- read.table(text='Date        name             score
12/09/2012  "Mahesh\nRahul"    120
13/09/2012  "abc\nxyz\nrep"         110', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

ns <- strsplit(df$name, '\n')
result <- lapply(lapply(lapply(df, rle), `[[<-`, 'lengths', sapply(ns, length)), inverse.rle)
transform(data.frame(result), name=unlist(ns))
#         Date   name score
# 1 12/09/2012 Mahesh   120
# 2 12/09/2012  Rahul   120
# 3 13/09/2012    abc   110
# 4 13/09/2012    xyz   110
# 5 13/09/2012    rep   110
```

Comment: +1 just for `readClipboard()` alone! What a handy function I never knew about.

Comment: @SimonO101 thanks, I removed it though. That way fails to read the newlines correctly.

Comment: Can you post the output of `str(df)` in your posting, or better yet, the ouput of `dput(df[1:3, ])`?